# JQuery script disables word highlighting

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using [this](http://nick-jonas.github.io/threesixtyjs) JQuery 360 rotate script for a product a website.

As you can see from the linked demo, you're not able to highlight words on the page. I've installed the script on my server and it's doing exactly the same.

What's causing this and how can this be fixed?

Comment: In which browser? In FF its working without problems...

Comment: Latest build of Google Chrome.

Comment: in file `jquery.threesixty.js` you can see `_disableTextSelectAndDragIE8();` and also there is other code to disable text selecting... so simply comment it out...

Comment: If you don't want to comment the 3rd-party script, you can just do `document.body.onselectstart = null;` in your script after the library is loaded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
/**
 * Disables text selection and dragging on IE8 and below.
 */
var _disableTextSelectAndDragIE8 = function() {
  // Disable text selection.
  document.body.onselectstart = function() {
      return false;
  };

  // Disable dragging.
  document.body.ondragstart = function() {
      return false;
  };
};
```

Looking through the script, I found this section of code.  Creating a breakpoint on the return line of the `onselectstart` and `ondragstart` event functions in Google Chrome resulted in the `false` being returned when I tried to highlight any text.

As suggested in the comments, try commenting out any `_disableTextSelectAndDragIE8()` function calls in the script